# Issue with counting events by time range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data export from software that tracks when people swipe access cards to unlock a door. I am trying to find out how many card swipes we get each for each two-hour block.

Something weird is going on. The formula works for only two of the time blocks, even though the first several rows of data show there are other time slots that should be recorded. I have made sure that all the right cells are formatted for the same category (Time) and type (*1:30:55 PM). In the attached screenshot, you can see the formula used.

[image]

I think the issue is this was a CSV export from the software, but from there I don't know where to go.  Any suggestions? And yes, I tried to do a pivot table first, but when I tried to group the data I got an error message saying something like "Excel can't group on this value."

Comment: With out a file to work with (minimally reproduceable example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) my guess is that some of the Times were imported as times and others as strings. Time values would be right justified by default as string values would be left justified by default. When you did the import of the .csv did you specify the column data types or just accept the defaults?

Comment: It was exported as a CSV file, so when opening that in Excel I accepted the default of each column being assigned to 'general.' And in my screenshot, the formula is from cell K6.

Comment: @RetiredGeek - And your statement about Time values being right justified tells me that something is wrong with every row where the time doesn't start with a double-digit number.  Maybe I need to choose a different Time type than "*1:30:55 PM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I opened the CSV export in a text editor and found there was a **leading space** before every hour entry. I had to use the search and replace to remove all the extra spaces. After that, I was able to successfully load it into Excel, all of the time entries were right-justified, and my formulas worked.